# Invalid Selector for finding element if element is displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to navigate to Centrebet and if the navigation menu does not exist under Sports, then I want to click Sports.  I have the below code though it keeps giving invalid Selector.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[id*='accordionMenu1_ulSports'][style*='display: none;']")
if element.is_displayed():
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class ='head-style3'][contains(text(), 'Sports')]").click()
```

I have also tried to use

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id = 'accordionMenu1_ulSports'][contains(text(), 'Soccer')]")
if element.is_not_displayed():
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class ='head-style3'][contains(text(), 'Sports')]").click()
```

It keeps giving invalid selector Any ideas?  Thanks[image]

Comment: Instead of `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class ='head-style3'][contains(text(), 'Sports')]").click()` use `element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class ='head-style3'][contains(text(), 'Sports')]").click()`. Also post complete exception details in your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani It seems to execute the job though its not clicking.   Is if element.is_displayed(): not a viable method?  No errors given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first XPath

```
"//ul[id*='accordionMenu1_ulSports'][style*='display: none;']"
```

is a mix of XPath and CSS selector. Pure XPath should looks like

```
"//ul[contains(@id, 'accordionMenu1_ulSports') and contains(@style, 'display: none;')]"
```

Your second XPath

```
".//*[@id = 'accordionMenu1_ulSports'][contains(text(), 'Soccer')]
```

will not match required `ul` as it doesn't have text node `"Soccer"`- it's text content of sibling link...

Try

```
//ul[@id='accordionMenu1_ulSports' and ./preceding-sibling::a[.='Soccer']]
```

Also webElement has no such attribute as `is_not_displayed()`. I guess you should try `not element.is_displayed()` instead.

Complete code should looks like

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='accordionMenu1_ulSports' and ./preceding-sibling::a[.='Soccer']]")
if not element.is_displayed():
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class ='head-style3'][contains(text(), 'Sports')]")
    element.click()
```

*Update*

To know whether `"Soccer"` element is accessible you can just check `"display"` style value of `"Sports"`:

```
sports = driver.find_element_by_id("accordionMenu1_ulSports")
if sports.get_attribute("style") == "display: none;":
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="menu_acc"]/li[3]/a').click()

soccer = driver.find_element_by_link_text("SOCCER")
```

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@id='accordionMenu1_ulSports' and ./preceding-sibling::a[.='Soccer']]"}

Comment: Are you sure that required element ("Soccer") present in DOM if "Sports" list is not opened? I cannot check it as website is not accessible for me...

Comment: You could download blockless or use setupvpn (extension) both free, to use an Australian Ip to access it.  Yeah line 33, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='accordionMenu1_ulSports' and ./preceding-sibling::a[.='Soccer']]") seems to give the issue.  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@data-type ='sports_l1'][contains(text(), 'Soccer')]") works.  I am curious why that is giving error

Comment: Your update gives no errors but it doesn't seem to click anything.

Comment: Sports menu remains closed and `sports.click()` do nothing, right? Does `soccer = driver.find_element_by_link_text("SOCCER")` gives you error?

Comment: Unable to locate element.  Yes it does give that error..  I was trying out SOCCER = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@data-type ='sports_l1'][contains(text(), 'Soccer')]") which did nothing